# Python - use cursor to perform SQL query, how do I find out if there were > 0 results from SQL?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, cursor

I have a python cursor that performs an SQL query, and then it outputs the results to a CSV, row by row:

```
conn_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=sde-db;DATABASE=SDE;READONLY=True"
conn_sde = pypyodbc.connect(conn_string) # create connection object
cursor = conn_sde.cursor() # create cursor object

sql_query = """
    SELECT
        OBJECTID,
        Property_Number
    FROM
        dbo.PROPERTIES
"""

cursor.execute(textwrap.dedent(sql_query))

## then iterates over cursor and writes rows ##
```

But I am now finding an issue whereby if there are zero results found with my SQL, it crashes my python script.

I am wanting to do the following type of thing:

```
if len(cursor) > 0:
  # write to CSV
else:
  # do something else
```

I know I cannot find the len() of a cursor, so how do I find the number of rows in the cursor, then still use that cursor if the number is > 0?

I hope the above is clear...

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Benno, you are almost there. Your way of approach is correct.

**Step 1:** First fetch the rows in the cursor.

```
fetch_result = cursor.fetchall()
```

**Step 2:** Check if there are any rows fetched

```
if fetch_result:
    # Write to CSV
else:
    # Whatever you want
```

Comment: if I use the `cursor.fetchAll()` as you have indicated, will I still be able to do a `for row in cursor:` where you have # write to CSV?

Comment: @Benno: The "fetch_result" will have all the rows. so you can use,

**    for row in fetch_result: **

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to do this:

```
all_rows = cursor.fetchAll()
if len(all_rows) > 0:
   # write to CSV
else:
   # do something else
```

Comment: if I use the `cursor.fetchAll()` as you have indicated, will I still be able to do a `for row in cursor:` where you have # write to CSV?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `cursor.rowcount`, as specified in Python's [PEP249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount)

Comment: you are spot on, I actually did come across that idea earlier, but I was having a 'boy look' and I wrote it as `cursor.rowcount()` which kept failing, clearly as I was including the brackets which are unnecessary. I am getting a result of -1 for my rowcount, and from what I can tell from the PEP249 this is probably acceptable as there would be no results, so it throws -1. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

you can do a simple :

```
cursor.execute(...)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

if rows:
    # write to csv
    for row in rows:
        print (row)
else:
    # do something else
```

row contains all values from the select clause.

Comment: That is how I am writing to my CSV, but I want to try to catch it if there is zero results...  I currently get an error if there are no hits. I thought there would be an easy equivalent of len()

Comment: uff now we should have it